# not able modify array object of parent controller in model controller in angularjs 1

Tags: angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have done the following :

```
 var appController = function ($scope,$uibModal) {
$scope.list = [
{
  "parentId": 0,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "node1",
  "description": "test",
  "canhaveItems": true,
  "canhaveSubNode": true,
  "items": [{ "id": "item1", "title": "item1" }],
  "nodes": [  ]
};


$scope.newTopNode = function () {
   var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
         templateUrl: '../modal.html',
         controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.handler = 'pop';
            $scope.buttonText = "Add Group";
            $scope.body = 'Add New Top Group';
            $scope.save = function () {
                var subNode = {
                    "parentId": 0,
                    "id": 100,
                    "title": $scope.txtGroup,
                    "description": $scope.txtDescription,
                    "canhaveItems": $scope.chbItems,
                    "canhaveSubNode": $scope.chbSubGroup,
                    "items": [],
                    "nodes": []
                };
        // here I need to update the parent List 
        //I tried like this 
        // $scope.list.push(subNode); // but parent list is not updating
                modalInstance.close();
            };
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
         }
    });
};
}
```

I have tried different things like using 
       resolve : function (){ return subNode;} 
       scope : $scope
       scope : this.parent 
but no use, looking for some help here on updating parent array object inside model controller.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a variable  in top controller

```
 var parent = $scope;
```

and accessed the list object in model controller like this

```
  parent.list.push(subNode);
```

Thanks.